# How to position an Awesome Font Icon after a text

Tags: font-awesome

I have used for the first time an Awesome Font Icon.

I have put it just after the text as below, but the arrow has gone just below the text.

```
<a class="button" href="/Contatti.html">xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">
```

How could I position it just close to the end of the text after the last charachter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap both with a span with:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```